# No me aparece error pero no se me ejecuta el código (JFrame)

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando y haciendo una prueba con Java. Técnicamente debería salirme una ventanita con un Hola Mundo (y el resto del texto que he puesto) pero no me sale nada.

El IDE no me da error y no veo el fallo por ningún sitio, ni sé que me falta.

¿Alguna sugerencia? El código es el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import sun.applet.Main;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class main extends JFrame {

    public main() {
        JLabel lblSaludo = new JLabel("Hola Mundo. Creando mi primer ejemplo");
        add(lblSaludo);
        this.setSize(400,200);
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar estas creando una instancia de una clase diferente a la que creaste, ya que en el método `main` tienes :

```
Main main = new Main();
```

Pero tu clase se llama main, sin mayúsculas por lo mismo debería ser

```
main ventana = new main();
```

Recuerda que Java es bastante exigente en cuanto a las mayúsculas y minúsculas.